# Two-body correlation function vs. two-body reduced density matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, density-operator, many-body, correlation-functions

The notions of two-body correlation function and two-body reduced density matrix appear frequently in the literature. But what are the precise meanings of them?

A notion more often heard of than the two-body reduced density matrix is the one-body reduced density matrix. In correspondence, is there a one-body correlation function too?

Comment: Where in the literature? can you give an example of such a work? Some more context would be useful

Comment: I agree, you have to give more context. Are you referring to non-relativistic condensed matter physics? DFT, RDMFT etc.?